# Connecting to Android x86 vm by USB/SSH

Tags: virtualbox, android, vmware, adb

Does anyone know, how can I connect by adb to virtual Android via USB or somehow else? I have rooted Android 7.1 on Vmware workstation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve an adb connection via network. Configure e.g. a connection to eth0 in bridged mode within vmware. (Bridged mode it is called in VirtualBox, in vmware there will be a similar mode.) Then run `ifconfig` within a terminal of the virtual android (terminal app or use alt+F1). You will find an IP number in the output. (For me it was within the wlan section, because android x86 connected the eth0 from the host as wlan to the guest.) With this IP number you can use the command `adb connect IP:5555` followed by `adb shell`.